# Is there a way to skip "Allow SSH-in-browser to connect to VMs." in Google cloud computing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I SSH into my VM, it takes about 30 seconds to connect. I usually go to other tabs to do my own stuff and come back after 10 minutes. Then it expires, even if I click authorize it will fail, I have to connect again.

This is annoying. Is there a way like some settings in the browser or my VM to skip this dialog?

Last year I can SSH into my VM without this prompt, but this year it pops up every time.

I want to click SSH, and go to other tabs, and when I come back in 10 to 20 minutes, it already connected in, not asking for authorization (like last year).

**Edit:**

Today, I tried to enter my VM, takes 7 retries. Every time I click SSH, I immediately went to do my work. When I came back, timeout. Stuck in this loop 7 times. When I finally logged in, the VM has some error that could be solved one hour earlier if I had logged in the first time.

This is so dumb. I can't believe this setting is intentional.

[image]

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,could you please have a look at this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accordingly proceed.

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu It does not solve my problem. I know if I install the gcloud CLI, I can have a specialized terminal to connect GCP and would not encounter this kind of problem. However, I want to keep this computer as simple as possible. I only want to use browser (chrome) to connect it, not installing gcloud. Last year, when I click SSH on browser, it will just connect into the VM without the prompt. So I still need an explanation why it happens this year.

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu Your answer "The actions you can take to identify the reason behind failed SSH connections" shows you don't understand my question. There is no SSH connection failure. The prompt requires user input to continue, but I would like to leave for 10 minutes or even 1 hour. After several minutes, the SSH connection will timeout, even if I authorize the prompt, it won't let me in. There is no error, just timeout. It seems like a designed behavior, but I want to get rid of the prompt, so I can leave for 1 hour and come back to an already connected VM, instead of a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no  way, like some settings in the browser or  VM to skip this dialog but there is a Cloud Shell: to use an online terminal with the gcloud CLI already set up, activate Cloud Shell.**

At the bottom of this page, a Cloud Shell session starts and displays a command-line prompt. It can take a few seconds for the session to initialize.

The below content taken from official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#reqs)

**The actions you can take to identify the reason behind failed SSH connections and to fix your connections are discussed in the following sections.**

> Observe the following steps before diagnosing unsuccessful SSH
> connections:
>
> 1.Install or upgrade the Google Cloud CLI to the most recent version.
>
> 2.Test your connectivity.
>
> 3.Install the Linux guest environment if you are using a custom Linux image that isn't currently running the guest environment.
>
> 4.See Troubleshooting OS Login if you use it.
>
> **If you are still facing an error You can either try connecting again or use the SSH-in-browser troubleshooting tool to troubleshoot an
> unsuccessful SSH connection.**
>
> Click Troubleshoot to launch the troubleshooting tool.Once the
> troubleshooting tool has been performed, take these actions:
>
> 1.Examine the test results to determine the cause of the VM's poor SSH connection.
>
> 2.Follow the tool's remediation instructions to fix SSH connections.
>
> 3.Reconnect to the virtual machine (VM) if possible.
>
> If the connection isn't successful, attempt manual troubleshooting by
> doing the following actions:
>
> [Debug issues using the serial
> console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#debug_with_serial_console)
>
> [Ensure the VM is booting
> normally](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/vm-startup)

Also Refer to  Priyam Singh’s Kloudle [Blog](https://https:/https://kloudle.com/academy/5-ways-to-connect-to-your-gcp-vm-instances-using-ssh/) on different ways to connect to your GCP VM instances using SSH for more information.